# Hide/Show components in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm really new to React Native and I'm wondering how can I hide/show a component.
Here's my test case:

```
<TextInput
    onFocus={this.showCancel()}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.doSearch({input: text})} />

<TouchableHighlight 
    onPress={this.hideCancel()}>
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>Cancel</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

I have a `TextInput` component, what I want is to show the `TouchableHighlight` when the input gets the focus, then hide the `TouchableHighlight` when the user press the cancel button.

I don´t know how to "access" the `TouchableHighlight` component in order to hide/show it inside of my functions `showCancel/hideCancel`.
Also, how can I hide the button from the very beginning?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var myComponent = React.createComponent({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            showCancel: false,
        };
    },

    toggleCancel: function () {
        this.setState({
            showCancel: !this.state.showCancel
        });
    }

    _renderCancel: function () {
        if (this.state.showCancel) {
            return (
                <TouchableHighlight 
                    onPress={this.toggleCancel()}>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>Cancel</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <TextInput
                onFocus={this.toggleCancel()}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.doSearch({input: text})} />
            {this._renderCancel()}          
        );
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, just one small change that I needed to do: onFocus={() => this.showCancel() } this needs to be a callback function.

Comment: Only worked for me after changing the `return ''` to `return null`

Comment: You can also do `{someBoolVal && <Component />}` and it will only show if the bool value is true.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: I don't know this is the accepted answer which not implementing the original desired functionality show/hide, but instead add/remove

Comment: @KiritModi  pls DONOT let return in a separate line alone . e.g. return \n (< TouchableHighlight > ...</TouchableHighlight>).  js would return without jsx component as you expect.  I am not sure if it's for  you case but for me i spent more than 2 hours to find the issue (maybe stupid).

Comment: also shorthand `{bool ? <Component /> : <OtherComponent />}`

Comment: As per my understanding we are removing the component from memory. What if we that component is loaded with some data ?

Comment: why is this better than the shorter answer?: { this.state.showTheThing && <TextInput/> }

Comment: Just curious, what's the difference between a function call that has an underscore in its name? ("_renderCancel" vs "toggleCancel")

Answer (score 197):

In your render function:

```
{ this.state.showTheThing && 
  <TextInput/>
}
```

Then just do:

```
this.setState({showTheThing: true})  // to show it  
this.setState({showTheThing: false}) // to hide it
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, I'm not sure why when I do something like `{ this.state.showTheThing && (<Text>foo</Text>  && <Text>bar</Text>)}` only "bar" is shown in the UI. I would expect "foo" and "bar" would be displayed. What I have needed to do to solve this is to call `{ this.state.showTheThing && (<Text>foo</Text>} { this.state.showTheThing && (<Text>bar</Text>}`

Comment: maybe this works? because the logical `&&` not combine elements `{ this.state.showTheThing && (<View><Text>foo</Text><Text>bar</Text></View>)}`

Comment: This worked for me , I wanted to show a "Next Step" button when a user uploaded their profilepicure . so my code was : ``{this.state.hasPic && <Button
          title="Go to next step"
          onPress={this._nextStep}
        />}``

Comment: For anyone struggling with showing more than one component, wrap your component with a fragment. eg. ```<React.Fragment><Text>Foo</Text><Text>Bar></Text></React.Fragment>```

Answer (score 53):

In react or react native the way component hide/show or add/remove does not work like in android or iOS. Most of us think there would be the similar strategy like

```
View.hide = true or parentView.addSubView(childView)
```

But the way react native work is completely different. The only way to achieve this kind of functionality is to include your component in your DOM or remove from DOM.

Here in this example I am going set the visibility of text view based on the button click.

[image]

The idea behind this task is the create a state variable called state having the initial value set to false  when the button click event happens then it value toggles. Now we will use this state variable during the creation of component.

```
import renderIf from './renderIf'

class FetchSample extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
      status:false
    }
  }

  toggleStatus(){
    this.setState({
      status:!this.state.status
    });
    console.log('toggle button handler: '+ this.state.status);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {renderIf(this.state.status)(
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            I am dynamic text View
          </Text>
        )}

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.toggleStatus()}>
          <Text>
            touchme
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

the only one thing to notice in this snippet is `renderIf` which is actually a function which will return the component passed to it based on the boolean value passed to it.

```
renderIf(predicate)(element)
```

> renderif.js

```
'use strict';
const isFunction = input => typeof input === 'function';
export default predicate => elemOrThunk =>
  predicate ? (isFunction(elemOrThunk) ? elemOrThunk() : elemOrThunk) : null;
```

Comment: Clever :) what's the use case for the thunk?

Comment: Haha. Brilliant!

Comment: This solution makes sense for use cases where a dialog box needs to render only when needed. Ty!

Comment: This won't work if you need to keep status, remove element reset his state. so each time you render again is like you create again component.

Comment: touchme (touchablehighlight) component moves up, how to prevent it from moving up?

Answer (score 38):

React Native's layout has the `display` property support, similar to CSS. 
Possible values: `none` and `flex` (default).
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#display

```
<View style={{display: 'none'}}> </View>
```

Comment: Careful not to use this with `position: absolute`, it doesn't actually hide it! Known bug from 0.54 - 0.59 (at least): https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18415

Comment: This is the answer that applied to my situation, which was having to press a hidden button programatically. I don't think many of the  other solutions would have worked for my specific problem, as if the button's not rendered, it can't be clicked.

Answer (score 24):

in render() you can conditionally show the JSX or return null as in:

```
render(){
    return({yourCondition ? <yourComponent /> : null});
}
```

Comment: Parentheses should be required in line 2.

Comment: Thank you for the simplest solution

Comment: Best solution. Simplest, clearest, and most easily testable.

Answer (score 20):

Most of the time i'm doing something like this :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isHidden: false};
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }
  onPress() {
    this.setState({isHidden: !this.state.isHidden})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.myStyle}>

        {this.state.isHidden ? <ToHideAndShowComponent/> : null}

        <Button title={this.state.isHidden ? "SHOW" : "HIDE"} onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If you're kind of new to programming, this line must be strange to you :

```
{this.state.isHidden ? <ToHideAndShowComponent/> : null}
```

This line is equivalent to

```
if (this.state.isHidden)
{
  return ( <ToHideAndShowComponent/> );
}
else
{
  return null;
}
```

But you can't write an if/else condition in JSX content (e.g. the return() part of a render function) so you'll have to use this notation.

This little trick can be very useful in many cases and I suggest you to use it in your developments because you can quickly check a condition.

Regards,

EDIT: For a more straight forward synthax, you can do `{this.state.isHidden && <ToHideAndShowComponent/>}`. Here, the left operand is evaluated before the right one, so if `isHidden` is false, then the component will not show up.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you defined <ToHideAndShowComponent/>

Comment: @Ritveak by <ToHideAndShowComponent/> he meant your own element you wanna hide or show... It is not a defined element, it is just an example.

Answer (score 13):

just use

```
style={ width:0, height:0 } // to hide
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add some context / detail to the answer.

Comment: Assuming you have a mechanism to decide which component to hide, this answer is quite useful. You can wrap whatever component you are trying to hide with a View with style={{width:0, height:0}}.

Comment: how do you restore the element to the original width and height?

Comment: don't understand why is this downvoted, but in many case it is good advice. I need to switch between animated and non-animated gif. Conditional switching img caused delays with no img at screen. As part of fix, I'm displaying both img, but the one who should be hidden has zero width and height.

Comment: This keeps the component in memory, which can be a problem with big components. Why not use the great examples above? They insert and remove component completely...

Comment: In most cases, I agree use a conditional to add or remove a component from you View. However, there are cases such as an overlay which will sit on top of it's siblings, blocking the UI, unless given a height of 0. I ran into this issue when using this module: https://github.com/eyaleizenberg/react-native-custom-action-sheet

Comment: {width:0} or {height:0} is enough

Answer (score 13):

I needed to switch between two images. With conditional switching between them there was 5sec delay with no image displayed.

I'm using approach from downvoted amos answer. Posting as new answer because it's hard to put code into comment with proper formatting.

Render function:

```
<View style={styles.logoWrapper}>
  <Image
    style={[styles.logo, loading ? styles.hidden : {}]}
    source={require('./logo.png')} />
  <Image
    style={[styles.logo, loading ? {} : styles.hidden]}
    source={require('./logo_spin.gif')} />
</View>
```

Styles:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logo: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
  hidden: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  },
});
```

[image: screencast]

Comment: This keeps the components in memory, which can be a problem with big components. Why not use the great examples above? They will insert the right picture and remove the other one completely...

Comment: any of those examples doesn't work properly when you try to create animated spinner. Like I already mentioned in my answer on android trying to switch img for anim gif, will cause 5s delay when no png nor gif is shown. I believe the delay is caused by loading gif into memory, which might take some time. However iOS seems to do much better job here. If you don't believe me, try it yourself.

Comment: Of course as pointed out it's not optimal solution for every component. But IMHO for loading spinner it's just fine. It will eventually be unloaded when user transition to another page.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

**Hide** And **Show** parent view of `Activity Indicator`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    isHidden: false
  }  
}
```

**Hide** and **Show** as Follow

```
{
   this.state.isHidden ?  <View style={style.activityContainer} hide={false}><ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#00ff00" animating={true}/></View> : null
}
```

**Full reference**

```
render() {
    return (
       <View style={style.mainViewStyle}>
          <View style={style.signinStyle}>
           <TextField placeholder='First Name' keyboardType='default' onChangeFirstName={(text) => this.setState({firstName: text.text})}/>
           <TextField placeholder='Last Name' keyboardType='default' onChangeFirstName={(text) => this.setState({lastName: text.text})}/>
           <TextField placeholder='Email' keyboardType='email-address' onChangeFirstName={(text) => this.setState({email: text.text})}/>
           <TextField placeholder='Phone Number' keyboardType='phone-pad' onChangeFirstName={(text) => this.setState({phone: text.text})}/>
           <TextField placeholder='Password' secureTextEntry={true} keyboardType='default' onChangeFirstName={(text) => this.setState({password: text.text})}/>
           <Button  style={AppStyleSheet.buttonStyle} title='Sign up' onPress={() => this.onSignupPress()} color='red' backgroundColor='black'/>
          </View>
          {
            this.state.isHidden ?  <View style={style.activityContainer}><ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#00ff00" animating={true}/></View> : null
          }
      </View>
   );
}
```

On Button presss set state as follow

```
onSignupPress() {
  this.setState({isHidden: true})
}
```

When you need to hide

```
this.setState({isHidden: false})
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue where I would want to show / hide Views, but I really didn't want the UI jumping around when things were added/removed or necessarily to deal with re-rendering.

I wrote a simple Component to deal with it for me. Animated by default, but easy to toggle. I put it on [GitHub](https://github.com/osagie/react-native-hideable-view) and [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hideable-view) with a readme, but all the code is below.

`npm install --save react-native-hideable-view`

```jsx
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Animated  } from 'react-native';

class HideableView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opacity: new Animated.Value(this.props.visible ? 1 : 0)
    }
  }

  animate(show) {
    const duration = this.props.duration ? parseInt(this.props.duration) : 500;
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.opacity, {
        toValue: show ? 1 : 0,
        duration: !this.props.noAnimation ? duration : 0
      }
    ).start();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.visible !== nextProps.visible;
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.visible !== nextProps.visible) {
      this.animate(nextProps.visible);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.removeWhenHidden) {
      return (this.visible && this.props.children);
    }
    return (
      <Animated.View style={{opacity: this.state.opacity}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }
}

HideableView.propTypes = {
  visible: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  duration: PropTypes.number,
  removeWhenHidden: PropTypes.bool,
  noAnimation: PropTypes.bool
}

export default HideableView;
```

Comment: Nice one, just what I was looking for :)

Comment: This works best, and behaves like a proper view when you put other components that have a lifecycle inside the view (which doesn't work with `visible && (...)`.

Answer (score 6):

An additional option is to apply **absolute positioning via styling**, setting the hidden component in out-of-screen coordinates:

```
<TextInput
    onFocus={this.showCancel()}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.doSearch({input: text})}
    style={this.state.hide ? {position: 'absolute', top: -200} : {}}
/>
```

Unlike in some of the previous suggestions, this would hide your component from view BUT will also render it (keep it in the DOM), thus making it truly *invisible*.

Comment: This idea suits for me, thanks. If anybody needs, look at it too: https://gist.github.com/jaysoo/cbb81a07cc22015a72e9

Answer (score 6):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: true,
}
}
```

**declare visible false so by default modal / view are hide**

example = () => {

```
 this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })
```

}

**Function call **

```
{this.state.visible == false ?
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress= {() => this.example()}>   // call function
                          <Text>
                            show view
                          </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

</View>
:
 <View>
    <TouchableOpacity
              onPress= {() => this.example()}>
                          <Text>
                            hide view
                          </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
</View> 
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

**Three ways to show\hide components:**

**- Class Component: / ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

in all examples i used below state:

```
.  
...
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {showComponent: true};
}
```

---

**1. using `display` prop**

```
<View display={this.state.showComponent ? 'flex' : 'none'} />
```

**2. using `display` prop with `style`**

```
<View style={{display:this.state.showComponent ? 'flex' : 'none'}} />
```

**3. limit render**

```
{
    this.state.showComponent &&
    <View /> // Or <View> ... </View>
}
```

---

---

**- Functional Component:/ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

in all examples i used below state:

```
const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(true);
```

---

**1. using `display` prop**

```
<View display={showComponent ? 'flex' : 'none'} />
```

**2. using `display` prop with `style`**

```
<View style={{showComponent  ? 'flex' : 'none'}} />
```

**3. limit render**

```
{
    showComponent &&
    <View /> // Or <View> ... </View>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need the component to remain loaded but hidden you can set the opacity to 0. (I needed this for expo camera for instance)

```
//in constructor    
this.state = {opacity: 100}

/in component
style = {{opacity: this.state.opacity}}

//when you want to hide
this.setState({opacity: 0})
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually use something like this

```
const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false)
return(
    <div>
         {showComponent && (<Text>Hello</Text>)}
         <Button onPress={() => {setShowComponent(true)}}>Click me</Button>
    </div>
)
```

It will show 'Hello' once the button is pressed. This is called conditional rendering. You can refer to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_conditional_rendering.asp)  to learn about conditional rendering.

Comment: corrected the useState syntax via Edit answer option. Any trusted community member kindly approve the edit. It's the best solution I was looking for and worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
// You can use a state to control wether the component is showing or not
const [show, setShow] = useState(false); // By default won't show

// In return(
{
    show && <ComponentName />
}

/* Use this to toggle the state, this could be in a function in the 
main javascript or could be triggered by an onPress */

show == true ? setShow(false) : setShow(true)

// Example:
const triggerComponent = () => {
    show == true ? setShow(false) : setShow(true)
}

// Or
<SomeComponent onPress={() => {show == true ? setShow(false) : setShow(true)}}/>
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Updated, explained a bit more. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use my module [react-native-display](https://github.com/sundayhd/react-native-display) to show/hide components.

Answer (score 2):

The following example is coding in typescript with Hooks.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

........

const App = () => {

   const [showScrollView, setShowScrollView] = useState(false);

   ......

   const onPress = () => {
    // toggle true or false
    setShowScrollView(!showScrollView);
  }

  ......

      </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
        <View>{showScrollView ? (<DetailsScrollView />) : null}</View>
      </MapboxGL.MapView>
  ......

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would vouch for using the opacity-method if you do not want to remove the component from your page, e.g. hiding a WebView.

```
<WebView
   style={{opacity: 0}} // Hide component
   source={{uri: 'https://www.google.com/'}}
 />
```

This is useful if you need to submit a form to a 3rd party website.

Answer (score 1):

i am just using below method to hide or view a button. hope it will help you. just updating status and adding hide css is enough for me

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
      this.state = {
      visibleStatus: false
   };
}
updateStatusOfVisibility () {
   this.setStatus({
      visibleStatus: true
   });
}
hideCancel() {
   this.setStatus({visibleStatus: false});
}

render(){
   return(
    <View>
        <TextInput
            onFocus={this.showCancel()}
            onChangeText={(text) => {this.doSearch({input: text}); this.updateStatusOfVisibility()}} />

         <TouchableHighlight style={this.state.visibleStatus ? null : { display: "none" }}
             onPress={this.hideCancel()}>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>Cancel</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
     </View>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in iOS development by `react-native` when I use `display: 'none'` or something like below:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  disappearImage: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  }
});
```

The iOS doesn't load anything else of the Image component like `onLoad` or etc, so I decided to use something like below:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  disappearImage: {
    width: 1,
    height: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -9000,
    opacity: 0
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide it but keep the space occupied by the component like css's `visibility: hidden` setting in the component's style `opacity: 0` should do the trick.

Depending on the component other steps in disabling the functionality might be required as interaction with an invisible item is possible.

Answer (score 1):

We now have hooks so I would recommend a reformat. Use hooks to turn components on/off.

`const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = setState(false);`

Then have a button

```
<Button title="Press Me" onPress={() => {
   setModalVisible(true);
}}
```

Then, inside your return statement

```
return(
<View>
    {modalVisible &&
   Insert modal code in here.
}
</View>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, using the useState Hook

```
The useState basically, is a feature which helps us preserve the values of variables even after multiple re-renders.
```

It acts a local state management tool, for storing values, after the component renders or re-renders.

In addition, to that you can also, trigger it to update the UI, by changing the value of the state variable.

`const [show,setShow] = useState(true)`

So, here we have destructured the, values that useState sends, first is the variable, through which we can get the value, and the second is a function through which we can update the state variables value.

So, in your case -

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
const [show,setShow] = useState(true)
return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
   {show && <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
     Showing and Hiding using useState
   </Text>}
    <Button
     title="Press me"
     onPress={() => {setShow(!show)}}
   />
 </View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
 backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
 padding: 8,
},
paragraph: {
 margin: 24,
 fontSize: 18,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 textAlign: 'center',
},
});
```

In this example, on Button press, we are toggling the state variable from true to false.

You can show or hide JSX Code, using boolean conditions, which we are doing in this statement.

```
{show && <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
     Showing and Hiding using useState
   </Text>}
```

This is an quick and effective method of using state for UI manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Very Easy. Just change to () => this.showCancel() like below:

```
<TextInput
        onFocus={() => this.showCancel() }
        onChangeText={(text) => this.doSearch({input: text})} />

<TouchableHighlight 
    onPress={this.hideCancel()}>
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>Cancel</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to show or hide a component in react native is checking a value of a parameter of app state like `state` or `props`. I provided a complete example as below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text,TextInput,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native'

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            show:false
        }
}

    showCancel=()=>{
        this.setState({show:true})
    };

    hideCancel=()=>{
        this.setState({show:false})
    };

    renderTouchableHighlight(){
        if(this.state.show){
           return(
               <TouchableHighlight
                   style={{borderColor:'black',borderWidth:1,marginTop:20}}
                   onPress={this.hideCancel}>
                   <View>
                       <Text>Cancel</Text>
                   </View>
               </TouchableHighlight>
           )
        }
        return null;
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <View style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',flex:1}}>
                <TextInput
                    style={{borderColor:'black',borderBottomWidth:1}}
                    onFocus={this.showCancel}
                />
                {this.renderTouchableHighlight()}

            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Here is the result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditions for show and hide the components

```
constructor(){

    super();

    this.state ={

      isVisible:true

    }
  }

  ToggleFunction = () => {

    this.setState(state => ({

      isVisible: !state.isVisible

    }));

  };

  render() {
  
    return (

      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

      {

        this.state.isVisible ? <Text style= {{ fontSize: 20, color: "red", textAlign: 'center' }}> Hello World! </Text> : null
      }

      <Button title="Toggle Visibility" onPress={this.ToggleFunction} />

      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I solve this problem like this:**

> `<View style={{ display: stateLoad ? 'none' : undefined }} />`

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use this because I wanted to use the "useRef" conditions were not an option for me. You can use this suppose when you want to use useRef hook and press the button.

```
   <Button
      ref={uploadbtn}
      buttonStyle={{ width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 0, display: "none" }}
      onPress={pickImage}
    />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
checkincheckout = () => {
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })
}

render() {
        return (
{this.state.visible == false ?
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 50 }}>

        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'column' }}>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.checkincheckout()}>

                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Click to Check in</Text>

            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>

    </View>
:
<View style={{ alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 50 }}>

<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'column' }}>

   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.checkincheckout()}>

        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Click to Check out</Text>

    </TouchableOpacity>

</View>

</View>
 }

);
}
```

thats all. enjoy your coding...