# Error showing/hiding component with state change in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to optionally show / hide a component within my react native app. A cut down version of the code I'm using was inspired by [Hide/Show components in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266831/hide-show-components-in-react-native). The code is as follows:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Text,
  Navigator,
} = React;


class SomePage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showView : true,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }

  testRender()
  {
    return (
      <Text>ShowView: {this.showView}</Text>
        )
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (this.state.showView){
      return ({this.testRender.bind(this)})
    }
    else
    {
      return (<Text>ShowView: {this.showView}</Text>)
    }
  }
}
```

The code is unfortunately not working, and is throwing an "unexpected token error" on the

```
return ({this.testRender.bind(this)})
```

If I write the line as

```
return (this.testRender.bind(this))
```

The error disappears but I just get a blank screen. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bind is not the correct way here. You need to call the function.

```
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (this.state.showView){
      return this.testRender();
    }
    else
    {
      return (<Text>ShowView: {this.showView}</Text>)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Dude! Thank you so much! This had me going in circles for a couple of hours!